# Amazon Cognito JS SDK

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to understand Cognito authentication using their JavaScript SDK. I have the following code (which is triggered by a form in a React application):

```
import {
    CognitoUserPool,
    AuthenticationDetails,
    CognitoUser
} from "amazon-cognito-identity-js";

const poolData = {
    UserPoolId: MY_POOL_ID,
    ClientId: APP_CLIENT_ID
};

export function cognitoLogin(credentials, callback) {
    const authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(credentials);

    const userPool = new CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser({
        Username: credentials.username,
        Pool: userPool
    });

    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: function(response) {
            console.log("SUCCESS!");
            console.log(response);
        },
        onFailure: function(error) {
            console.log("FAILURE!");
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

I generated a Client App without a secret. I generated a User and used the custom domain UI to login with that user and confirm it. However, when I try to login through the SDK I get a

```
{
    code: "NotAuthorizedException",
    message: "Incorrect username or password.",
    name: "NotAuthorizedException"
}
```

error. What could I be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `credentials` object must contain the keys `Username` and `Password` - notice they have first letter capitalized but yours seem to be all lowercase.